# Mix Audio tracks with offset in SOX

Tags: audio, mp3, ffmpeg, flv, sox

From ASP.Net, I am using FFMPEG to convert flv files on a Flash Media Server to wavs that I need to mix into a single MP3 file.  I originally attempted this entirely with FFMPEG but eventually gave up on the mixing step because I don't believe it it possible to combine audio only tracks into a single result file.  I would love to be wrong.

I am now using FFMPEG to access the FLV files and extract the audio track to wav so that **[SOX](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sox/)** can mix them.  The problem is that I must offset one of the audio tracks by a few seconds so that they are synchronized.  Each file is one half of a conversation between a student and a teacher.  For example teacher.wav might need to begin 3.3 seconds after student.wav.  I can only figure out how to mix the files with SOX where both tracks begin at the same time.

My best attempt at this point is:

```
ffmpeg -y -i rtmp://server/appName/instance/student.flv -ac 1 student.wav 
ffmpeg -y -i rtmp://server/appName/instance/teacher.flv -ac 1 teacher.wav 

sox -m student.wav teacher.wav combined.mp3 splice 3.3
```

These tools (FFMEG/SoX) were chosen based on my best research, but are not required.  Any working solution would allow an ASP.Net service to input the two FMS flvs and create a combined MP3 using open-source or free tools.

**EDIT:**
I was able to offset the files using the `delay` switch in SOX.

```
sox -M student.wav teacher.wav combined.mp3 delay 2.8
```

I'm leaving the question open in case someone has a better approach than the combined FFMPEG/SOX solution.

Comment: "sox -M student.wav teacher.wav combined.mp3 delay 2.8" solution works if each audio has one channel. if each sample is stereo I believe you can do "sox -M student.wav teacher.wav combined.mp3 delay 2.8 2.8 0 0".  I think sox automatically alters the volume/gain though and something else has to be added to the command to make is sound right...  Thanks for the solution!

Comment: Nvm, this is possibly a better generalized way to go about it:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327262/sox-mix-and-delay/12378408#12378408

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, this *should* be possible with a combination of [`-itsoffset`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options) and the [`amix` filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#amix), but a [bug with `-itsoffset`](http://roundup.libav.org/issue359) prevents it.  *If* it worked, the command would look something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i student.flv -itsoffset 3.3 -i teacher.flv -vn -filter_complex amix out.mp3
```