# Sox mix and delay

Tags: sox

I am mixing audio using SOX.

the command `SOX -m voice.wav audio.wav final.wav` is what I am using.

My goal is to delay the voice.wav of 10 second, if I try to use delay 10.0 then I have double voice.

How to get right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://sox.sourceforge.net/Docs/FAQ

> There are a couple of options:
>
> ```
> sox -M f2.wav f3.wav f1.wav out.wav delay 4 4 8 8 remix 1,3,5 2,4,6
> ```
>
> (assuming stereo), or
>
> ```
> sox -m f1.wav "|sox f2.wav -p pad 4" "|sox f3.wav -p pad 8" out.wav
> ```
>
> The second way is probably better since it works with files with any number of
>   channels.

Comment: #5yearslater

I've been attempting this same method (from the SoX FAQ) but no matter what I do it returns the error "Can't open input pipe '|sox f3.wav -p pad 8': premature EOF

Any clue what that would be happening? It does the same thing when i try to delay as well... this is in Node using sox-audio btw

Answer (score 7):

```
sox voice.wav pad 10 0
```

```
sox -m voice.wav audio.wav final.wav
```

Comment: I already solved the problem time ago with your similar code, but I vote you as no many developers answer questions after one month !!!

Comment: nice answer dude. you save my life