# Sox mixing with a delay

Tags: audio, delay, wav, mixing, sox

I have a problem with mixing sounds with delay.

I run this

`sox -M f1.wav f1.wav f1.wav f1.wav out.wav delay 3 3 4 4 5 5`

In the final file volume of the sound is changing(decreasing). How can i avoid this.

Comment: Answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327262/sox-mix-and-delay/12378408#12378408

Answer (score 1):

You can also control the volume for each of the signals using -v. You hadn't asked for this, but my experience is that at some point you might use this. And it took me a while to find this option online.

```
sox -m -v 1 file1.wav -v 0.5 file2.wav out.wav
```

Hope someone finds this useful.

Answer (score 0):

While `man sox` does not describe automatic attenuation for merge (-M), this surprises me.
The following applies to "mix" mode (-m)

> Unlike the other methods, 'mix' combining has the potential to cause
>   clipping in the combiner if no balancing is performed. So here, if
>   manual volume adjustments are not given, to ensure that clipping does
>   not occur, SoX will automatically adjust the volume (amplitude) of
>   each input signal by a factor of ¹/ n , where n is the number of input
>   files. If this results in audio that is too quiet or otherwise
>   unbalanced then the input file volumes can be set manually as
>   described above; using the norm effect on the mix is another
>   alternative.

So even though the manual explicitly excludes all modes other than "mix", I would certainly try the 'norm' effect or otherwise specify volume adjustments, since I cannot see how one would merge signals whilst avoiding clipping without attenuating somewhere.